# Unable to center the content section in every screen for a full screen no scroll website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been struggling to make a custom website responsive. It is a full screen no scroll website. I have been trying to make the content section center and the footer section at the bottom of the sidebar on every screen size. I mean no matter whichever screen size the website is accessed on I want the content to be at the center and the language drop-down menu and copyright to be always at the bottom. I tried doing that with different media queries but then again different screens which have different height and screens ruin it. Please check this website www.matininternational.com.  And here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zakero/x9got1br/3/

```
.content {
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    top: 130px;
    width: 660px;
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}


.background-overlay{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 100px 0 0;
}
```

Please note that I haven't used any css frameworks to make the design. It is my own concept.

Answer (score 0):

I have used flexbox to algin the content of section in center like this:

```
section-name{
display:flex;
justify Content: center;
align item:center;
width:100%;
height :400px;
}
```

https://scrimba.com/g/gflexbox